# Fourier Transform of Mp3 File

Tags: java, mp3, fft

I want to take Fourier Transform of Mp3 file.For this first I am reading that file using `AudioInputStream` and then converting in Required Audio format,

```
AudioFormat decodedFormat = newAudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
        baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(),
        baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(), false);
```

It is giving me a very huge byte of array. Now divide this byte array into small size chunks(4096 bytes)and pass it to Fourier Transform Function and continue for whole array.This process slow Down my system.and it is taking 15 minute to process a single mp3 song. So How i can solve this problem?
I am using this code for Fourier Transform-- http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html

Comment: If your FFT on that amount of data is taking 15 minutes you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @Alnitak-in the code of above link they mention that this code reallocate memory for the subarray instead of reusing.When i divide Pulse Code Modulated Byte of array of song after reading in 4096 byte i have to call fft method  approx 7000-8000 times and it slows the system.So what i should do????

Comment: get a better FFT?  I found a [link](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=113796) that talked about a BASIC (!) implementation performing a 4096 sample FFT in 3.5ms.  In 2005 !

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!!.But i am not getting from that link.

Comment: The link was just for comparison to show that the link you supplied appears to fail the "fast" part of "FFT".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fourier Transform of mp3 file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223422/fourier-transform-of-mp3-file-in-java)

Comment: @Paul R- ya But still i didnt get the answer...

Comment: I got it!!!!!!  https://code.google.com/p/tonic/source/browse/tonic/src/tonic/audio/FFT.java?r=43 this link helped me!!!!

Comment: see, you did get an answer (above).  You got a better FFT!

Comment: @PaulR that other question already got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's taking 900 seconds (15 minutes) to generate 9000 FFTs with 4k points (i.e. 100ms per FFT) then your FFT implementation is broken.

You need to find a (much) more efficient FFT implementation.

Comment: Now i am using https://code.google.com/p/tonic/source/browse/tonic/src/tonic/audio/FFT.java?r=43 this FFT code.It is working well.But in this code i have doubt on line Number-119,why they are dividing sqaure root of square of real and imaginary by m.length.

Comment: @Himanshu I expect the division is to maintain a consistent spectral power density